# Python library function to re-apply a function to its own output until output remains unchanged?

Tags: python

Some algorithms are best performed by repeatedly applying a function to its own output.

In my example, it's removing matching pairs of letters.

For example if you have the string, `ztWqqWtUU`:

```
remove_pairs('tWqqWtUU') -> 'ztWWt'
remove_pairs('ztWWt') -> 'z'
remove_pairs('z') -> 'z'
```

Obviously this can coded in a loop, that makes a note of the "last value" and checks if it's changed. But is there a library that will do this for me?

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is _recursion_. You don't need some 3rd party library to do that.

Comment: This sounds like something better achieved by keeping a stack of unmatched letters. Trying to do this by applying a partial solution in a loop ends up with quadratic runtime on inputs like `'ab'*100000 + 'ba'*100000`.

Comment: Also, even with the repeated application approach, a loop seems like a better idea than recursive calls. It'll be faster, simpler, and with less risk of blowing the recursion limit.

Comment: Also, library recommendation questions aren't allowed on Stack Overflow due to spam problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
def remove_all_pairs(string):
    new_string = remove_pairs(string)
    if new_string == string:
        return new_string
    else:
        return remove_all_pairs(new_string)
```

That would give you the recursion you need.